# Where is the Xcode setting for the project's own header files?

Tags: xcode, xcode6, header-files, xcode6.1

I want to understand exactly how Xcode is searching for header files that are part of the project (not system or library headers), but I can't find any reference to the project directory in the build settings.  The setting **Header Search Paths** has only a system path.  Where and how is the project search path controlled?

I ask because I want to start breaking files into *folders* (not just groups), and I want to make sure this isn't going to cause problems with includes.  It seems to work okay, but I don't know how Xcode is doing it. It's something more complex than a simple search path.

For example, if I have two headers of the same name, one in a group (with a corresponding folder), and one at the top level, like this:

> Thing.h (1)
>   Top.cc
>   Group1/Thing.h (2)
>   Group1/Inner.cc

For `Top.cc` to get (1) and (2) it must say `#include "Thing.h"` and `#include "Group1/Thing.h"`

For `Inner.cc` to do the same, it must say `#include "../Thing.h"` and `#include "Thing.h"`.

That's nice, but where is the setting? What is the compiler flag? I don't see it.

(I realize this type of nesting is less useful in Objective-C, because you can't put a class in a namespace, but I'd like to use it for my C++ code.)

Comment: The rule of thumb is that if you add a header anywhere in the project source file hierarchy then Xcode will find it at compile-time - I think it effectively just adds a `-I` for each directory in the project that contains one or more header files.

Comment: I did look at the command line in the build log. I don't see anything like that. Maybe this question is more about clang.

Comment: That's odd - if I look at the `CompileC` command line for one of my Xcode projects I see plenty of `-I` switches for the relevant directories in the project.

Comment: I've got some -I flags, but not to project dirs. Some are to binary .hmap files. I guess I'll just trust the magic for now.

Comment: Oh – that explains it – you are using precompiled headers.

Answer (score 2):

See the [Header-Map Build Settings](https://web.archive.org/web/20160827070103/https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/XcodeBuildSettingRef/1-Build_Setting_Reference/build_setting_ref.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003931-CH3-SW158) in the Build Setting Reference documentation.

Quote:

> Header maps (also known as “header maps”) are files Xcode uses to compile the locations of the headers used in a target. These files use the suffix .hmap. Xcode passes the header maps it puts together to C-based compilers through the -I argument.

I suppose setting `HEADERMAP_INCLUDES_PROJECT_HEADERS` is what you're looking for.